# Best way to pass address of "char path[MAX]" to a param of "const char*" in Swift

Tags: c, swift

I realize there are a million variations of the "how do I convert `char[]`/`char*` to a Swift Sting" question out there, and their inverse, all of which have been asked and answered.

I'm not asking that.

All I want to do, in Swift, is to simply pass the address of a C `char` array (obtained via a C function) to the C `char*` pointer argument of another C function.

Specifically, I'm trying to replicate the following C code, where the address of the `char` array contained in the `stat.f_mntonname` field gets passed as the first parameter of `getattrlist(const char*, ...)` call:

```
// Get volume stat
const char* path = ...;
struct statfs volStat;
if (statfs(path,&volStat)==-1) { error }

// statfs has the mount point of the volume; use that to get attributes
struct attrlist request;
// ... set up request here
struct volAttrs {
    // ... response values
}

if (getattrlist(volStat.f_mntonname,&request,&volAttrs,sizeof(volAttrs),FSOPT_NOFOLLOW)==-1) { error }
```

The problem seems to be that Swift interprets the `stat.f_mntonname` field, not as an array, but as a tuple containing `MAXPATHLEN` number of `Int8` values; in other words, `(Int8,Int8,Int8,Int8,Int8,...,Int8)`.

After much poking around on the internet, I was ultimately able to find this workaround:

```
var volStat = statfs()
guard statfs(fileURL.path, &volStat) != -1 else {
    ErrorExit(cause: "statfs")
}
var attrRequest = attrlist()
// set up getattrlist request ...
var attrs = XtraVolumeAttrs()
guard getattrlist(UnsafeRawPointer(&volStat.f_mntonname.0).bindMemory(to: CChar.self, capacity: Int(MAXPATHLEN)),
                  &attrRequest,
                  &attrs,
                  MemoryLayout<XtraVolumeAttrs>.size,
                  UInt32(FSOPT_NOFOLLOW)) != -1 else {
    ErrorExit(cause: "getattrlist")
}
```

So the magic `UnsafeRawPointer(&volStat.f_mntonname.0).bindMemory(to: CChar.self, capacity: Int(MAXPATHLEN)` seems to accomplish the task of casting the `char[MAXPATHLEN]` array into a `char*`, but boy is it ugly, unintuitive, and—if I'm being completely honest—I'm not even sure this is correct (other than the fact that the code works).

I feel there's got to be a better way and I was hoping someone would post it.

Comment: Note that the use of `Unsafe[Raw][Mutable]Pointer(&x)` is almost always incorrect, as it creates a dangling pointer in most cases. I'm hoping to resurrect [#20467](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/20467) soon to warn (and eventually error) on such code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *is* ugly because Swift imports C arrays as tuples, and there is no automatic conversion to arrays or pointers.

As pointed out by Hamish, the use of  `UnsafeRawPointer(&volStat.f_mntonname.0)` is incorrect, because the created pointer might be invalid on return from the initializer.

A safe version is

```
let retval = withUnsafeBytes(of: volStat.f_mntonname) { 
    getattrlist($0.bindMemory(to: Int8.self).baseAddress, /* other args */)
}
```

Here `bindMemory()` is called on the “buffer pointer” covering the raw bytes of the tuple, so that we don't have to specify the capacity explicitly.

Comment: While I *believe* this always should work in OP's case (where the struct variable is initialised within the same function), I would be wary of using it in other cases, as the optimiser can create specialised functions that pass struct fields individually. In that case, it might notice that only the first element is being used and therefore only pass that value. For example, [this gist breaks when compiled in Release mode](https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/1fa4e6e7bebd6751c8230e8c1a091dd6). Therefore in the general case I would advise using `withUnsafeBytes`.

Comment: @Hamish: Thanks as always (I had a little doubt myself :) – I will have a look at your example later.

Comment: Thanks @MartinR and @Hamish! I assume by "safe" you mean that the reference into the local stack is contained within the scope of the closure—and isn't just floating around, possibly beyond the lifespan of the structure?